# How to save changes to disk with Entity Framework when connection goes down so next time app starts it propagates the changes

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, t-sql

Is it possible to keep on to the 'changes' you will be wanting to make with Entity Framework?

For instance I do an update query then the connection fails, I close the app and then tomorrow I want it to do that update query when a connection is restored.

Is a thing like that possible with Entity Framework 6?

Comment: Im general it would be a bad idea. As the context follows the unit of work principle, you would end up with inconsistence. So if your scenario supports what you asked, you will have to implement yourself. Remember, the connection is not kept open, thus the app is not notified about any change in connectivity, you get the status only when trying to acccess the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly create your own ChangeTracker, like in this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/entity_framework/entity_framework_track_changes.htm), which saves all changes to a file. Parsing the file for a later use might be tricky.

The other option would be to use [retry logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/connection-resiliency/retry-logic) and hope the connection problem was just a slight hiccup

Answer (score 0):

I think `ZorgoZ` is right and this answer will not address your actual question, but what I think it is your actual problem (see [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)): you fail to save some changes (business-wise) and you want to be able to retry saving them later, not necessary some EF changes that you want to persist a later moment.

One way to do it is to store the business information that trigger the change and retry the whole flow:

- define some sort of queue stored in a file, isolated storage etc. (depends on your technology)
- your update flow should persist some sort of record / object in the queue that contains all relevant information + a status (e.g. Queued, Save error etc.)
- update is tried. If it fails, you can have a status update (e.g. Save error)
- the user closes the application
- later, the user opens the application seeing the queue items status (item 1 saved OK, item 2 save error etc.)

Besides EF technical issues, this implementation allows for flow changes that include things outside EF save changes (e.g. also check some external API) and abstracts away the data access layer entirely (EF changes serialisation implementation has a big chance to depend on some EF specifics).

Also I sense context information serialization (e.g. data behind some form) is easier to implement than EF context changes serialization.

Comment: You're right, I didn't even think about this possibility. Seemed like I was stuck in some wrong thought loop. Thanks for helping out.